# "Infinite scroll web page" web crawler

Tags: web, webkit, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have no idea to crawl infinite scroll page (e.g. [google image](https://www.google.com.tw/search?um=1&es_sm=93&hl=zh-TW&authuser=0&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=dog&oq=dog&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1442.3760.0.3919.8.6.2.0.0.0.73.339.6.6.0....0...1c.1.51.img..0.8.349.dwQq0MQdqcw)),
have anyone can suggest me which "python toolbox" could do that or examples ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you scrape AJAX pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260540/how-do-you-scrape-ajax-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Try selenium for python it has a web driver that allows to emulate a browser, so you can scroll tha page and load the content.

Selenium instalation page: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/selenium_installation/installing_selenium_libraries/