# How to scrape ajax loaded division?

Tags: php, ajax, perl, curl, simple-html-dom

The title says it all. Please give me some way for how to scrape AJAX loaded Division.

There is one website which has Product Grid Division. I want this division for scrap the data from it but the problem is when i get the page content data in another html page there is no product grid because it's loaded via AJAX after some time. For Scrapping i tried both Perl and CURL with PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What page (url)  would you like to scrape?

Comment: PHPhil sorry i can't declare url

Comment: @SinanÜnür Thanks for advice but you don't know about me and you have to respect each and every programmer even if he/she fresher. I just want to know how to scrape the Division which is load with AJAX. I can't get that division id when i print that page content. I am scrapping data from last 4 months so i have enough skill to do this. If you don't know the answer then please don't comment.

Answer (score 1):

From [WWW::Mechanize::FAQ](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#Which-modules-work-like-Mechanize-and-have-JavaScript-support)

> Which modules work like Mechanize and have JavaScript support?
>
> In no particular order: Gtk2::WebKit::Mechanize, Win32::IE::Mechanize,
> WWW::Mechanize::Firefox, WWW::Scripter, WWW::Selenium

Also see: [How do you scrape AJAX pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260540/how-do-you-scrape-ajax-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), e.g. through [Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Selenium-Remote-Driver/), you will be operating real browsers to access the site. Sites can be quite sensitive to subtle differences in browser behavior.

Comment: i don't know how to use this. Can you please help me?

Comment: Depends on the pay ...