# Get dynamic content

Tags: php

I would like to get the URLs of all products from [this page](https://www.lidl.ch/c/de-CH/wochenaktion/a10041837?channel=store&tabCode=Current_Sales_Week).

This is how I try to get the first item:

```php
function getXpath($url) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($contents === false) {
        die('Error. Please check the URL.');
    }
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($contents);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
    return new DOMXPath($dom);
}

$xpath = getXpath('https://www.lidl.ch/c/de-CH/wochenaktion/a10041837?channel=store&tabCode=Current_Sales_Week');
$x = $xpath->query("//a[@class='grid-box__pdp-link']")->item(0)->textContent;
var_dump($x);
```

The result is *NULL*.

If I check this page on my browser and also disable JavaScript, I see that the products are not getting loaded, so they must be loaded dynamically. Is there another way how I could get the URLs of the products?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623192/how-to-scrape-ajax-calls-in-php

Comment: "Is there another way how I could get the URLs of the products?" ... headless browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL that you are looking for is already in the source code. You may find it as the value of a `canonicalurl` attribute.

This will return the relative URL of the first item:

```php
$xpath->query("//div[@data-selector='PRODUCT']/@canonicalurl")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

If you want all URLs, use this loop:

```php
$canonicalUrl = $xpath->query("//div[@data-selector='PRODUCT']/@canonicalurl");
for ($i = 0; $i <= $canonicalUrl->length; $i++) {
    echo $canonicalUrl->item($i)->nodeValue . '<br>';
}
```