# How to scrape Ajax data from a website

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, fetch, scrapy

I am trying to get data of the website

www.deutsches-krankenhaus-verzeichnis.de/suche/Bundesland/Nordrhein-Westfalen.jsf

This page is using ajax and i could not figure out how can i grab that data. As i have tried curl and other methods.

Please provide some suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: They could use a kind of protection to prevent you from doing this (session checking, refer checking)

Comment: yes might be, that is what i am not able to get, they are calling whole page using ajax call, and when i see this link they are using "http://www.deutsches-krankenhaus-verzeichnis.de/suche/_files/main-search/Suchergebnis.jsf", but still this page again using same call.

Comment: and the tricky part is when you view source, you won't find any listing data there.

Comment: In the best situation, what is the result you want. A list of hospitals?

Comment: Yes, i need list of hospitals and its link, so that i can automate the process and in next page i can get other informations, but on this page i need Hospital names and its links.

Comment: Its strange, i only get 404 GET ajax calls in my console, while the hospitals ere loaded

Comment: yes very strange, i wonder what they are using to prevent. If you find please provide any idea.

Comment: I only know that these results are listed in the table with the id 'searchResults'. And that this table is hidden at start, however, i cannot find the script in which the hidden is changed in to visible. You can try contacting the company and explain why you need this names and links.

Comment: yes i also found that ID, even i am not able to find anything with that, I need data for my client, anyway thank you for the effort.

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260540/how-do-you-scrape-ajax-pages ?? Merry christmas :)

Comment: $html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.deutsches-krankenhaus-verzeichnis.de/suche/Bundesland/Nordrhein-Westfalen.jsf');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( '//*[@id="searchResults"]' );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}

Answer (score 0):

You can go for CasperJS (http://casperjs.org/)
Here is the small example for this 
(http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-scraping-script)

Answer (score 0):

When using curl you just get the source of the original page, without any javascript being executed. Try using some headless browser solution such as PhantomJs to load the page and execute the javascript. It allows you to query the page with css selectors after the Ajax data has been loaded.

http://phantomjs.org

Comment: can you please give me an example as i couldn't figure out how to work with phantomjs.