# Scrape and Extract data from https://nforlanwebdmz.phs.org when it is not visible in 'Source Code' of the webpage

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, data-extraction

I am trying to write an automated PHP script to scrape and extract all 'Job IDs' (3262, 3197, 3196 etc.) from URL https://nforlanwebdmz.phs.org/ltmprd/CandidateSelfService/controller.servlet?dataarea=ltmprd&context.session.key.HROrganization=90&context.session.key.JobBoard=EXTPHYS&context.session.key.noheader=true.

However, this does not seem to be straightforward because the required data is not directly visible in the source code of the webpage. I also tried inspecting 'Developer Tools->Network' of different browsers, however could not locate the source of the data.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards!

[image: Developer Tools->Network]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take look at the Developer Tools>Network on Chrome, and found this API url:
[https://nforlanwebdmz.phs.org/ltmprd/soapExt/ldrest/JobPosting/JobPostingListWebServices_ListOperation?JobBoard=EXTPHYS&LocationOfJob=+&Category=+&WorkType=+&JobRequisition=+&**Description_translation_**=+&JobPosting=+&PostingStatus=2&PostingDateRange.Begin=+&PostingDateRange.End=+&JobRequisitionPriority=+&csk.IsoLocale=en&HROrganization=90&*limit=-1&*=1486230138234](https://nforlanwebdmz.phs.org/ltmprd/soapExt/ldrest/JobPosting/JobPostingListWebServices_ListOperation?JobBoard=EXTPHYS&LocationOfJob=+&Category=+&WorkType=+&JobRequisition=+&__Description_translation___=+&JobPosting=+&PostingStatus=2&PostingDateRange.Begin=+&PostingDateRange.End=+&JobRequisitionPriority=+&csk.IsoLocale=en&HROrganization=90&_limit=-1&_=1486230138234)

The "Job ID" is the "JobRequisition" in the JSON data

Comment: Yes Afif @afifzafri, this indeed is the URL I was looking for. But can you please tell me, what could be the reason that I could not find the same URL in Developer Tools->Network on Chrome? Do you use any special filters in Developer Tools? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you did not get the url. Nope I don't use any special filters in the Developer Tools. All I did was, open the link you give, then open the developer tools>network, and choose/click on the "XHR" tab and reload the page. Then just wait until the page is fully loaded. Try do it multiple times, sometime the dev tools does not "catch" the url properly

Comment: Can you please tell me which version of Chrome are you using? I'm having Version 55.0.2883.87 m. Thanks!

Comment: Strange but I am neither getting to see this particular API URL in Chrome nor in Firefox [51.0.1 (32-bit)].

Comment: Yes I'm also using the same Chrome version, Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)

Comment: Can you also please help me out finding the source of data on URL https://chenmed.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/jencare/? Regards!

Comment: I found out another way to get the url, so just open the page, open the dev tool> network. Then, you see on the website there is the "Search Jobs" button. Clicked it, and then the URL will show up :) maybe before this I accidently clicked it

Comment: Yes Afif, clicking on the 'Search Jobs' button brings that URL. Please let me know if you find something for the other URL https://chenmed.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/jencare/. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like I cannot find the API url for the new website you give. All I got is the initiator is from a file name "WorkdayApp", but I can't find it in the source.

Comment: I suggest you to try using library for scraping the content. You could try using the SimpleHTMLDom as suggested by Muhammad Athar. 
Before this I manage to scrape from a website that load ajax data using Selenium with Python language.

Comment: Even if I use some library such as SimpleHTMLDom, will I be able to scrape content whose source is unknown? How will I provide that invisible content as input to SimpleHTMLDom class?

Comment: try look at headless browser, that's the way that can scrape website that use ajax. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260540/how-do-you-scrape-ajax-pages

Answer (score 0):

Try **SimpleHTMLDom** to scrape date from any dom object.
Download Link from http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/