# How to scrape invisible html?

Tags: web-scraping

Is it possible?

For example values of this data table are hidden in html source:

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/european-dated-brent-swap-futures_quotes_settlements_futures.html

Comment: Might want to update that title, scrap != scrape

Comment: Which language or you using?

Comment: I am using `R` mainly.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the below example. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/5081/FUT?tradeDate=04/06/2018&strategy=DEFAULT&pageSize=500", False
        .send
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    vJSON = vJSON("settlements")
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Scraping is based on parsing XHR response by URL http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/5081/FUT?tradeDate=04/06/2018&strategy=DEFAULT&pageSize=500, which you can find in logged requests in browser (e. g. Chrome) developer tools on network tab after the page is loaded.

The output of the above code with requested parameters `tradeDate=04/06/2018&strategy=DEFAULT&pageSize=500` for me as follows:

[image: output]

Take a look how to manage with Chrome developer tools and get the necessary URL [in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20vba%20json%20%22developer%20tools%22).

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

Comment: I have no idea how did ya get that address site with chrome tools for programmers :O

Answer (score 1):

Technically they are not invisible, the values you look for are not in the initial HTML document that you requested. for more explanation read this [How do you scrape AJAX pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260540/how-do-you-scrape-ajax-pages)