# Read dynamically created content from webpage

Tags: javascript, c++, curl

I know of the curl library for C++ and can successfully read the HTML code from a webpage. However, the webpage in question loads some of their content with Ajax. Is there a way to execute the js code so I can read the entire page?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260540/how-do-you-scrape-ajax-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zombie.js](https://github.com/assaf/zombie) is a lightweight framework for testing client-side JavaScript code in a simulated environment.

This is using Node.JS, it will simulate the browser and open the webpage, allow you control the elements in webpage after ajax.